# A button class that prevents code repetition

Tags: android, kotlin

I was trying create a Button that makes the user to a new Activity, i create something like that:

```
//Main Activity
btnChangeScene.setOnClickListener { goToActivity(this, SecondActivity::class.java) }



fun Context.goToActivity(activity: Activity, classs: Class<*>?) {
        val intent = Intent(activity, classs)
        startActivity(intent)
        activity.finish()
    }
```

But when I try to go back to MainActivity, I need to create a new "goToActivity" inside SecondActivity and that's so bad for any programmer, because for every new activity, I need to create a new "goToActivity" inside it.

How can I get this same function implemented inside this class, so I can just call this function, instead of having to create it every time I create a new activity?

```
class ButtonActivity(private val button: Button): Activity(){

// code here
}
```

Comment: copy that method to some utility classes inside as a static method and call it from there

Comment: `because for every new activity...` use only one activity then

Comment: You need to declare it as top-level function. You also might as well restrict the receiver to an `Activity` and remove the activity argument. The `finish` call also probably shouldn't be there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

create a new kotlin companion object like below.

```
companion object AnyName {

fun Context.goToActivity(activity: Activity, classs: Class<*>?) {
        val intent = Intent(activity, classs)
        startActivity(intent)
        activity.finish()
    }
    }
```

now you call this function from any class.

Comment: This works for me, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Some possible solutions could be

1. Declare your navigation method at top level

For example make a Helpers.kt file and paste your *goToActivity* there

2. Switch to single activity with multiple fragments and you will be able to use some third party solutions like [jatpack navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation)
   . Or you can write your own function in main like:

   ```
   public void navigate(Fragment frag) {
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, frag);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();
   }
   ```